# How are the two statements same mathematically?

Tags: statistics, risk-assessment

I am doing a data course on statistics and in one of the questions, they're suggesting that the statements given below are mathematically the same. I disagree. Can they be mathematically proven to be the same?

> If we invest to improve safety in Midtown, there is a 25% chance we'll
> save $1,000,000 and a 75% chance we won't save any money.

> If we invest to improve safety in Midtown, we are certain to save
> $250,000.

Comment: You're right, they're not the same at all.

Comment: A mathematically exact statement would be:
"The expected value of our savings by investing in the safety of Midtown is  250,000."  That's just how much you expect to get "on average" given your current knowledge of the odds. But an average of possibilities isn't the same as a possibility of average. 
Here's an example to get the point across:
"If you play Russian Roulette, you have $\frac{1}{6}$ chance of getting hit by $1$ bullet, and  $\frac{5}{6}$ chance of getting hit by $0$ bullets." vs "If you play Russian Roulette, you are certain to be hit by one sixth of a bullet".

Comment: How can they be the same if there's a high likelihood that you won't save any money in the first scenario, but an absolute certainty that you will save $250K in the second scenario?

Comment: It might be useful if you could quote **exactly** what they wrote, word for word, without attempting to interpret or reword it in any way. Alternatively, if what you wrote is exactly what was written in the course, did you pay for this and, if so, can you get your money back?

Comment: I wrote is exactly as it was provided and I paid for it :(

Comment: Thanks everyone, good to know that I am not completely stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If we invest to improve safety in Midtown, there is a 25% chance we'll save \$1,000,000 and a 75% chance we won't save any money."

$$\implies \mathbb{E}[saving] = 0.25(1,000,000) + 0.75 (0) = 250,000$$

"If we invest to improve safety in Midtown, we are certain to save $250,000."

$$\implies \mathbb{E}[saving] = 1 (250,000) = 250,000$$

As you can see, **the statements produce a different weighted sum**. But those weighted sums both evaluate to the same number.

That is probably what the question means by "mathematically equivalent". Not to say they worded the question well at all :)

Comment: Can you help me understand why you did the calculations using weighted sum, please?

Comment: When talking about probability, and you get a list of percentages that sum to $100\%$, often the natural thing is to calculate the weighted sum to figure out some "expectation". In this case, the question wants you to explore "How much am I expected to save?". In the first scenario, it is 1million 25% of the time, 0million 75% of the time, meaning you are expected to save $25\%(1million)+75\%(0)$.  In the second statement, you certainly (100% of the time) get 250thousand. So your expected saving is $100\%(250thousand)$

Comment: But all that to say.... The weighted sum themselves tell VERY different stories, but it just so happens they evaluate to the same number